# Citing Math Proofs.

Tags: geometry, article-writing

I am writing a math paper on which $p$-gons are constructible by compass and straightedge and the construction of the $17$-gon. I am taking many proofs (but writing them in my own words) from a book, so that I can show another result. How exactly would I go about citing those proofs? If they are all from the same book, would I cite each one individually, or cite all of them at the end,after they have all been proven (they appear concurrently in the paper)? Additionally, if I am showing Felix Klein's solution to the construction of the $17$-gon, how would I cite that, seeing as the proof is rather long? Thanks!

Comment: Just say "the following seven theorems (or however many) follow closely the treatment in XXX" (and cite where I put XXX your reference to that book in your bibliography section)

Comment: I say: cite each one individually, by page number in the book.

Comment: Did you also plan to include Gauss's work on this problem in your references?

Comment: I suggest a combination of Gregory and GEdgar's solutions: say "The next 7 theorems closely follow Smith's treatment [Smith86]; for each, the relevant pages in that work are listed after the theorem." and then when you write the theorem, wrote something like this: "Theorem 2: The 3-gon is constructible. [Smith p. 73--74]."

Comment: Hardmath, I am discussing Gauss's work on cyclotomic polynomials, but I am not using his "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, " so I will not be referencing him specifically. John Hughes, thank you very much! That's sounds like quite a good idea.